# How to switch status in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have select options that I need to select 1 option at the time and set `active` value of selected item to `true`

So far I can make that, but the issue is:

When I change my selected option, first option `active` will not be set to `false`

## Screenshot

[image: one]

## code

`HTML`

```
<ion-row>
    <ion-col *ngFor="let imf of allImages" size="4">
      <img [id]="imf.id" (click)="getName(imf)" [src]="imf.src" [alt]="imf.id">
    </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

`Component`

```
allImages = [{
    'src' : '../../../assets/bgs/01.png',
    'id'  : '01',
    'name':  '01.png',
    'active': false,
},
{ 
  //and so on...
}];

getName(data) {
    // add class to selected option
    var titleELe = document.getElementById(data.id);
    titleELe.classList.add('active');

    // set active value of selected option to "true"
    let index = this.allImages.indexOf(data.id);
    data.active = true;
    this.allImages[index] = data;

    // issues:
    // remove added class from old item
    // remove "true" from old item
}
```

## What I need

1. remove added class from old item
2. remove "true" from old item

**Any idea?**

Comment: Why do you need active for? Just for highlighting or for any other usecase?

Comment: @Supercool. at the moment I am just using it as of debugging but i thought it might become useful for future updates.

Comment: @Supercool. already solved bro, see my answer, if you saw any issue in it please don't hesitate to tell me about it

Comment: you are going long way i see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solved

here is my last update which fixed my issues

```
getName(data) {
    const items = this.allImages.filter((item) => { // loop all items
      if(item.active == true) { // if any of them is set active to true
        item.active = false; // set it to flase
        var titleELe = document.getElementById(item.id);
        titleELe.classList.remove('active'); // and remove the class of it
      }
    });

    var titleELe = document.getElementById(data.id);
    titleELe.classList.add('active'); // add class to new selected item

    const index = this.allImages.indexOf(data.id);
    data.active = true; // set newly selected item active to true
    this.allImages[index] = data;
}
```

Hope it can help others as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ngClass` for setting '`active`' class

HTML

```
<ion-col *ngFor="let imf of allImages;let i=index" size="4">
      <img [id]="imf.id" [ngClass]="{'active':currentItemIndex == i}"  
(click)="setActiveItemIndex(i)" [src]="imf.src" [alt]="imf.id">
        </ion-col>
```

TS:

```
//property
currentItemIndex=0;

setActiveItemIndex(i){
   currentItemIndex=i;
}
```

In case in future you want to get the image which is active

```
const activeImage=this.allImages[currentItemIndex]
```